# How to enqueue music to default android music player via app?

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am new to android app development, but I have good knowledge of programming in JAVA and in general. I am trying to write an app for android which can enqueue music files to default music player in android (like Google Play Music). My app decides which song to play when, but I don't want to write a full-blown music player app. I just want to feed the existing player app with new music.

I am looking for something like "inter-app" communication (perhaps using Intent?) through which I can feed content to the music player and probably control the player itself.

I am not sure if such facility exist in android, so other alternative suggestions are also welcome. Also, please let me know if I didn't explain the problem properly.

Answer (score 1):

Intents are a very powerful feature of Android to which there isn't any direct analog in Java.  What you want to use is a mechanism known as an implicit Intent.  Normally, when you launch one activity from another, you create an Intent and specify which activity to start.  With an implicit Intent, you provide an action (`Intent.ACTION_VIEW`) and data (a URI pointing to a music file). Using an implicit Intent, you have a piece of data handled without knowing in advance which Activity will do the handling.

When you pass your Intent to `startActivity()`, the OS will attempt to resolve the data in the best way possible, typically popping up a list of apps that can possibly handle your data.  The user selects the appropriate app and that app handles the Intent, playing your music file.  Any app that registers as a service capable of potentially handling your data will show up in the list.  After passing the Intent, your activity will go into the background, and the app handling the intent will come to the foreground.

Once the user has selected an app to handle the Intent from your Activity, that app will always be used to handle that kind of Intent by your Activity until you delete your own app's data.

Take a look at the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to get yourself started and then ask a new question when you have a more specific problem you're trying to address.

Here's a code sample that demonstrates a very simple implicit Intent example, by which a URL is opened without knowing which browser will open it:

```
package com.marsatomic.intentimplicitdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public final static Uri URI = Uri.parse("http://www.marsatomic.com");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_connect);
        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, URI);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer MarsAtomic. Is it possible to decide the target app in advance without asking the user for which app to choose every time my app needs to play file? Also, I think I have a fairly specific problem. I want my app to control the music player and feed the content to it. When my app starts running it should load certain music files and enqueue them to the music player and start the music player. Also, I know this can be accomplished by making my app an independent music player. I am looking for alternative solution in which I can avoid writing a music player.

Comment: Added third paragraph to my answer to clarify things for you. Using implicit Intent, you absolutely can avoid writing a music player. If your question is answered, please mark the answer as "accepted" for the benefit of future readers and create additional, specific follow up inquiries in a new question.

Comment: This solution will make it possible to open the URI using Music Player. I am also looking for a way to control the music player from my app (play/pause/stop etc.)